Pseudo-Elements not working properly on Mui table head and Mui table row but working fine in windows browsers
i am giving background color and border color with border radius to mui table head and mui table row.
it looks fine in windows and android all browsers but seems like position not working in mac and iphone system.
i am adding windows chrome view and safari browser view.
i setup the code on code sandbox so you can see issue by opening link in windows chrome and safari mac os.
for debugging purpose i apply same css on mui box and it was working fine in safari also. seems like issue with using Pseudo-elements positions.
i want this with Pseudo-elements method. i ll be very thankful to you if you resolve this issue.
windows chrome browser view
safari browser view
background color and border is targetting table tag instead of staying inside thier parent relative.
here is code sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/silent-dream-txtxrl?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.tsx
This is index.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Demo from './Demo';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <Demo />
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

This is Demo.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import { Paper, Box } from "@mui/material";

import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

function createData(
  name: string,
  calories: number,
  fat: number,
  carbs: number,
  protein: number
) {
  return { name, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [
  createData("Frozen yoghurt", 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0),
  createData("Ice cream sandwich", 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3),
  createData("Eclair", 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0),
  createData("Cupcake", 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3),
  createData("Gingerbread", 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9)
];

const StyledTableHead = styled(TableHead)(() => ({
  position: "relative",
  zIndex: 0,
  backgroundClip: "padding-box",
  borderRadius: "10px",
  "&::after": {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 1,
    left: 1,
    right: 1,
    bottom: 1,
    background: "red",
    border: "1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18 )",
    content: '""',
    zIndex: -1,
    borderRadius: "10px"
  }
}));

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(() => ({
  position: "relative",
  zIndex: 0,
  backgroundClip: "padding-box",
  borderRadius: "10px",
  "&::after": {
    border: "1px solid transparent",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 1,
    left: 1,
    right: 1,
    bottom: 1,
    background: "yellow",
    border: "1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18 )",
    content: '""',
    zIndex: -1,
    borderRadius: "10px",
  },
}));

export default function BasicTable() {
  return (
    <>
      <Box
        sx={{
          height: "300px",
          width: "300px",
          position: "relative",
          zIndex: 0,
          backgroundClip: "padding-box",
          borderRadius: "10px",
          "&::after": {
            position: "absolute",
            top: 1,
            left: 1,
            right: 1,
            bottom: 1,
            background: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)",
            border: "1px solid rgba( 255, 255, 255, 0.18 )",
            content: '""',
            zIndex: -1,
            borderRadius: "10px"
          }
        }}
      >
        here box
      </Box>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
          <StyledTableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </StyledTableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows.map((row) => (
              <StyledTableRow
                key={row.name}
                sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
              >
                <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {row.name}
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.calories}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.fat}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.carbs}</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">{row.protein}</TableCell>
              </StyledTableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
}

This is package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "latest",
    "@emotion/styled": "latest",
    "@mui/material": "latest",
    "@types/react": "latest",
    "@types/react-dom": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "typescript": "latest"
  },
  "description": "https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.16.0/docs/data/material/components/table/BasicTable.tsx",
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "latest"
  },
  "main": "index.tsx",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  }
}


Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Please check codesandbox link.

Nope, although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

I have added the code, so please check the post now.

I'm guessing it might have to do with the fact, that this relies on position: relative to set the reference point for the absolutely positioned pseudo elements. In CSS 2.1, the effect of position: relative on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements was undefined. That has been modified in CSS Positioned Layout Module Level 3 - but question would be, whether Safari actually implemented this "update" ...?

i am not sure, that's why i decided to bring this problem to seniors like you. Can u please fix the problem?
